# Spring Data Jpa создание пользовательских запросов

Tags: spring, spring-jpa

При создании пользовательского запроса и использовании его в последующем в других методах, получаю ошибку создания бина, не понимаю, что не так
Есть CommentEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment_table")
@Data
public class CommentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @Type(type="date")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column
    private String message;

    @Column
    private boolean approved;

    @Column
    private Integer rate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private UserEntity author_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private GameObjectEntity post_id;
```

Запрос находится в CommentEntityRepository

```
@Query("select f from CommentEntity f where f.post_id = :gameObjectEntity")
ArrayList<CommentEntity> getAllByPost_id(@Param("gameObjectEntity") GameObjectEntity gameObjectEntity);
```

Comment: а что за ошибку то получаете?
можете приложите ее к вопросу?

Comment: Зачем называть поле в котором хранится `UserEntity` -  `author_id` ? вы же там не ID а объект храните

Comment: не_пользуйтесь_snake_case'ом , в Java есть Naming Convetions https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html согласно ему SNAKE_CASE вы можете использовать только в  константах и то только с верхним регистром.

Comment: Во всех остальных случаях используется CamelCase

Comment: И да...еще...не обязательно к НАЗВАНИЯМ классов сущностей добавлять Entity. Аннотации более чем достаточно...да и семантически это как то не очень...это получается вы каждый раз при создании нового объекта создаете не новый комментарий, а новую сущность комментария, что немного разные вещи

Comment: Вставил вашу сущность и репозиторий к себе в проект и написал тест. И что удивительно, даже в таком виде оно работает. `start test > 
com.stackoverflow.ru.model.CommentEntity@e4ca109
com.stackoverflow.ru.model.CommentEntity@677cc4e8
com.stackoverflow.ru.model.CommentEntity@4c6bba7d
com.stackoverflow.ru.model.CommentEntity@41e8d917
com.stackoverflow.ru.model.CommentEntity@2ae5bd34
 < end test`

Comment: Все ищется по объекту GameObjectEntity даже с таким неймингом

Comment: так что нужно искать ошибку где-то еще...ну и как приложите текст ошибки- напишите